# How do i make a foreign/primary key case insensitive in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the following code:

in one model

```
class Foo < AR::Base
    has_many :bars, foreign_key: :email, primary_key: :email, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And in another model:

```
class Bar
    belongs_to :foo, foreign_key: :email, primary_key: :email
end
```

How do i make it so that the `email` is case insensitive as the foreign key and primary key for both models?

Comment: Why don't you downcase your email before saving?

Comment: It would be nice to have a good answer for this question. If it didn't say :email, but rather :xyz, would just arbitrarily downcasing make sense?

Answer (score 1):

I use utf8_unicode_ci collation for my tables (ci stands for case insensitive) which allows me to query without being concerned about the case of the text. If you make your table or at least column case insensitive, then it should just work with queries...

(Note this works for MySQL)

Comment: @TJChambers please read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html to understand how collation affects querying. It is directly responsible for comparing column value to queried value and matching them. User wanted query to be case insensitive which you can achieve by using case insensitive collation rule set.